# EAN/GTIN Barcode Product Identifier - Barcode to Product Name

Tags: barcode

Does anyone know of a good online API that can translate EAN/GTIN barcodes to the product name (and if possible anything extra such as category?)

I have been unable to find one that has a good success rate, below are some barcodes from items just scanned around my house (nothing rare or obscure)

Example barcodes:

```
5010186014550
20411336
21048753
5449000000996
5051413363249
```

Comment: have you found out something? checked out my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this: http://openean.kaufkauf.net/

- here is the API link for it: http://openean.kaufkauf.net/api.php

or this:  http://www.codecheck.info/

Both are in german but the language doesn't matter, EAN is EAN :).
try your barcodes there, maybe the database contains your EAN's.

Answer (score 3):

This database seems even larger:

[ean-search.org](http://www.ean-search.org/)

They also have a REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comprehensive one from Norway:
http://glnservice1.gs1.no/GS1GepirClient/GepirClient.aspx

Regards
Arnfinn